# display specific index multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

i have an multidimensional array like this, but i just only need some index to be displayed,

```
Array

    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [1] => 220
                [38] => 200
                [232] => 970
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 220
                [2] => 190
                [39] => 200
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [1] => 190
                [3] => 40
                [50] => 220
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [2] => 40
                [4] => 200
                [57] => 120
            )
    )
```

then i just want to display only index [1] and [3], so it would be like this

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 220
            [2] => 190
            [39] => 200
        )


    [3] => Array
        (
            [2] => 40
            [4] => 200
            [57] => 120
        )
)
```

i try using this code

```
$order = array(1,3);

uksort($graph, function($key1, $key2) use ($order) {
    return (array_search($key1, $order) > array_search($key2, $order));
});
```

but still, its displayed the rest array that i dont need it that's key [0] and [2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Like this:**

```
foreach(array_keys($graph) as $key) 
{    
    if($key == 0|| $key == 2)
    {
        unset($graph[$key]);
    }
}
```

print_r

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 220
            [2] => 190
            [39] => 200
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [2] => 40
            [4] => 200
            [57] => 120
        )

)
```